# Get route by name and params for vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, json-ld, vue-router

I am using Vue with vue-router. For product items in a list view I would like to generate JSON-LN annotations with the `url` attribute set to the path of the product detail view.

I know I can get the current route's path by using `this.$route.path` but is there a way to get a distinct route path as it would be rendered with

```
<router-link :to={name: 'ProductDetail', params: {id: some_id, slug: some_slug}}></router-link>
```

to inject the route's path somewhere else?

Comment: Hey Till, is there anyway you can put any detail about how structured your Vuejs to get product urls?

Comment: @Mdunbavan Can you specify the problem your are facing? The router-specific answer is posted below. But another problem was, that for JSON-LD you need to specify the full url which is not part of the route. For that, I used this solution: http://developmentnow.com/2016/07/13/webpack-injecting-server-urls/

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You are looking for the [Router instance's `resolve` method](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-instance.html):

> Given location in form same as used in `<router-link/>`, returns object with the following resolved properties:
>
> ```
> {
>   location: Location;
>   route: Route;
>   href: string;
> }
> ```

In your case you could do something like this to get the url:

```
let props = this.$router.resolve({ 
  name: 'ProductDetail',
  params: { id: some_id, slug: some_slug },
});

return props.href;
```

Comment: Hi thanksd this looks promising. With the props above how could I inject that into the component for the product detail when you click on the route? Would it go inside the component itself?

Comment: @Mdunbavan why do you need to inject it? You can access the current route's name and parameters via `this.$route.name` and `this.$route.params`.

Comment: @thanksd because that would indeed return this route's info, but not info for other routes, which is what OP (and myself) want. Your answer looks like it'll work though. I'm trying to get meta data from different routes based on name, and I think this will work. It'd be cool if you could do something like `this.$router.ProductDetail...` but I guess it's obvious why that wouldn't work.

Comment: I noticed that if the route has no parameters (for example `this.$router.resolve({ name: "Admin" });`) then it doesn't return an object, just a the path as a string. Just something for others to note when using `$router.resolve`.