# How to change Vuetify tabs together with vue-router programmatically

Tags: vue.js, routes, tabs

How to change Vuetify tabs together with vue-router

I use vuetify tabs and router see eg. [How to use Vuetify tabs with vue-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721710/how-to-use-vuetify-tabs-with-vue-router)

In this sample exist two child component Foo and Bar.

I would like to change active tab and route from Foo or Bar component .
This is simplified example. I have the standard Vue structure (main.js, App.vue, Foo.Vue, Bar.vue)

I can change only router via this.$router.replace

Thanks.

**JS**

```
const Foo = {
  template: '<div>Foo component!</div>'
};

const Bar = {
  template: '<div>Bar component!</div>'
};

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar },
];

const router = new VueRouter({ routes });

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
});
```

HTML

```
<v-app dark>
  <v-tabs fixed-tabs>
    <v-tab to="/foo">Foo</v-tab>
    <v-tab to="/bar">Bar</v-tab>
  </v-tabs>
  <router-view></router-view>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `replace` directive to your v-tab:

```
<v-tab to="/foo" replace>Foo</v-tab>
```

The key is in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721710/how-to-use-vuetify-tabs-with-vue-router) you linked:`v-tab` is a wrapper for `router-link`. Adding the `replace` prop to a router-link tells it to call `router.replace()` instead of `router.push()` (from the [API Reference](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#replace)).

Comment: Nice!  It works. But I have problem with slider. Slider does not fallow the selected tab if selection happened via router.replace().   Have you anyidea about this?

Comment: If you have a route that partially matches another route try adding `exact` to the v-tab. The route `/` partially matches everything and without `exact` Vuetify may match it to other routes and think that it's the active tab