# v-tab router-link only activated when clicked on text

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple v-tab with router link :

```
        <v-tab>            

          <router-link
            class="normalize font-weight-bold"
            to="/docs"
            >
            Docs
          </router-link>

        </v-tab>
```

*Problem:*
The link works only when clicked exactly on the text **'Docs'**. I want to be able to switch tabs when clicked on the tab area for a better UX. How should I edit the code such that the user can switch tabs when s/he clicks on the tab area ?

Comment: I believe you should move the routing into the tab  like this `<v-tab to="/docs">Docs</v-tab>` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49721711/14072498

Comment: Thanks ! This solved my problem. Please add your comment as a reply so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should move the routing into the tab like this

```
<v-tab to="/docs">Docs</v-tab>
```

See also this question for related information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49721711/14072498