# Show a specific router path via JavaScript (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using vue.js 2 with routers.
I want to show the user a other route URL with javascript alert message.

For example the user is on the route: /register, and i want to show you the link of /login.
How can i do it?

```
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {            
        alert(this.$router.LINK_TO_PATH) //What comes here?
    },

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Having a link or getting the URL of a specific page? Read this one? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html

Comment: From the article: this.$router.push('/dashboard'). how can i show the link  Instead of go to it

Comment: Try this one `this.$router.options.routes.find(route => route.name === 'login').path` I guess?

Comment: `$router.options.routes` gives you all the available routes in your Vue router, then you can simply find the one you're interested in and display it as you wish.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927637/get-route-by-name-and-params-for-vue-router